# Como imprimir sem quebra de linha em Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, matriz, impressora

```
matriz = []
def create_matriz(a, b):
    for contador in range(a):
        matriz.append( [0] * b )

def print_matriz(txt):
    cont = 0
    for j in range(a):
        for i in range(b):
            if txt[cont] == "0":
                matriz[i][j] = 0
            elif txt[cont] == "1":
                matriz[i][j] = 1
            print txt[cont]
            cont += 1

code = " #Aqui vai uma sequência de 441(21 x 21) algarismos zeros e uns/Não 
coloquei porque da problema"
a = 21
b = 21
create_matriz(a, b)
print_matriz(code)
```

Seguinte, tenho este código para ler uma string com 441 algarismos, e colocá-los dentro de uma matriz de inteiros.

Até ai tudo bem.

Porém na hora de imprimir, ao invés de imprimir como uma matriz (sem quebra de linha), para cada um dos 441 algarismos, imprime uma nova linha.

Como faço pra não quebrar linha e imprimir um quadro com dimensões de 21 x 21?

ex:

`000000000000000000000
110111011111011111110
010101000100010100010
010101111111010101110
010100000101000101000
011101111101110101110
000001010100010100010
011111010111011101010
000000010001000001010
011111010111011111010
010100010000010101000
010111110111110101110
010000000100000000010
010111110101110111110
010101010101010100000
010101011101010111010
010101000001010001010
010101011111011111010
010001010000000000010
011111011111111111111
000000000000000000000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi a pergunta, uma possível solução seria essa:

```
# Criando a string com 441 zeros
zeros = 441*'0'

# Variável para a divisão da string
split = 21

# Criando a "matriz" a partir da string
matrix = [zeros[i:i+split] for i in range(0, len(zeros), split)]

# Imprimindo o resultado
print (matrix)
```

[Veja o resultado nesse link.](https://repl.it/I8Zi)

Answer (score 3):

Apenas adicione `end=''` e pronto!

Detalhe, adicionei a linha: `from __future__ import print_function` para colocar os parenteses no print por que não consegui adicionar o `end=''` sem os parenteses.

o `end` ele tem como padrão `"\n"` que é a quebra de linha no final do print, colocando `''` ele não quebra linha.

Veja : https://repl.it/I7lY/1

```
from __future__ import print_function

matriz = []
def create_matriz(a, b):
    for contador in range(a):
        matriz.append( [0] * b )

def print_matriz(txt):
    cont = 0
    for j in range(a):
        for i in range(b):
            if txt[cont] == "0":
                matriz[i][j] = 0
            elif txt[cont] == "1":
                matriz[i][j] = 1
            print (txt[cont],end='')
            cont += 1

code = """
000000000000000000000
110111011111011111110
010101000100010100010
010101111111010101110
010100000101000101000
011101111101110101110
000001010100010100010
011111010111011101010
000000010001000001010
011111010111011111010
010100010000010101000
010111110111110101110
010000000100000000010
010111110101110111110
010101010101010100000
010101011101010111010
010101000001010001010
010101011111011111010
010001010000000000010
011111011111111111111
000000000000000000000"""
a = 21
b = 21
create_matriz(a, b)
print_matriz(code)
```

**Saída:**

```
000000000000000000000
110111011111011111110
010101000100010100010
010101111111010101110
010100000101000101000
011101111101110101110
000001010100010100010
011111010111011101010
000000010001000001010
011111010111011111010
010100010000010101000
010111110111110101110
010000000100000000010
010111110101110111110
010101010101010100000
010101011101010111010
010101000001010001010
010101011111011111010
010001010000000000010
011111011111111111111
```

Comment: essa é a forma correta. Melhor ainda se o programa for feitoem Python 3 - a última versão do Python 2. - a 2.7, foi feita em 2010 - e nenhuma das melhorias da linguagem desde então foi incorporada ao Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Antony Gabriel, da forma que você passou realmente não quebrou a linha, porém a cada 21 eu queria quebrar.
Portanto fiz um complemento:

`def print_matriz(txt):
    cont = 0
    quebra = 0
    for j in range(a):
        for i in range(b):
            if txt[cont] == "0":
                matriz[i][j] = 0
            elif txt[cont] == "1":
                matriz[i][j] = 1
            if quebra < 20:
                print (txt[cont],end='')
            else:
                print (txt[cont])
            cont += 1
            quebra += 1
        quebra = 0`

Coloquei o contador 'quebra' pra poder fazer esta quebra de linha a cada 21, e agora sim ficou uma matriz 21x21.
Muito obrigado!

Comment: A minha solução ficou menor, mais legivel, mais pythonica e, provavelmente, muito mais rapida. :-)

Comment: E mais flexivel, ja que vc pode variar o 21. ehehehe!

Comment: Ainda vou aprender tudo isso. Comecei a aprender Pascal nesse semestre, mas como já tinha aprendido um pouco de lógica a uns anos atrás decidi aprender paralelamente uma nova linguagem.
Ai escolhi python, e com o tempo vou aprendendo essas novas ideias haha

Comment: Eu apenas reciclei o seu algoritmo, a quebra de linha ocorria no "\n" ao final da string da variável code, mas tudo bem, eu já sabia que de alguma forma eu não interpretei o problema corretamente hehe, desculpe.